# TikZ: How to hide the labels

Tags: tikz-pgf

If I have some coordinates with labels. 
Is there a tricky (global) command, that hides all the labels? 
So that I can use that like a shifter.

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm, tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate[label=A] (A) at  (0,0);
\coordinate[label=45:B] (B) at  (1,2);
\coordinate[label=right:C] (C) at  (0,1);

\foreach \P in {A,B,C} \draw[fill=black!1] (\P) circle (1.75pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just set their opacity to zero. For your convenience this answer defines a style `hide labels` that does that.

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm, tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{hide labels/.style={every label/.append style={text opacity=0}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate[label=A] (A) at  (0,0);
\coordinate[label=45:B] (B) at  (1,2);
\coordinate[label=right:C] (C) at  (0,1);

\foreach \P in {A,B,C} \draw[fill=black!1] (\P) circle [radius=1.75pt];
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}[hide labels]
\coordinate[label=A] (A) at  (0,0);
\coordinate[label=45:B] (B) at  (1,2);
\coordinate[label=right:C] (C) at  (0,1);

\foreach \P in {A,B,C} \draw[fill=black!1] (\P) circle [radius=1.75pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]